# Паттерн MVP. Кто ты, WebView - View или Model?

Tags: android, webview, mvp

Всем привет, строю MVP архитектуру в своём проекте и возникли проблемы в `WebView`. Посмотрите внимательно на этот класс.

```
public class LoginWebView extends WebView
{
    public LoginWebView(Context ctx)
    {
        this(ctx, null);
    }

    public LoginWebView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(ctx, attrs);
        getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
    }

    public void authorize(LoginCallback callback, GameProvider provider, String login, String password)
    {
        setWebViewClient(new LoginWebViewClient(callback, provider, login, password));
        setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        loadUrl(provider.getLoginPage());
    }

    class LoginWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
    {

        private LoginCallback callback;
        private GameProvider provider;
        private String login, password;
        private boolean jsInjected;

        public LoginWebViewClient(LoginCallback callback, GameProvider provider, String login, String password)
        {
            this.callback = callback;
            this.provider = provider;
            this.login = login;
            this.password = password;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if (!jsInjected)
            {
                jsInjected = true;
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Login script...", 1).show();
                loadUrl(provider.getLoginScript(login, password));
            }
            else
            {
                setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                setWebChromeClient(new LoginWebChromeClient(callback, provider));
                loadUrl("javascript:(function() { alert(document.documentElement.outerHTML); })()");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error)
        {
            setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            callback.onError("Ошибка подключения");
        }

    }

    class LoginWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient
    {
        private LoginCallback callback;
        private GameProvider provider;

        public LoginWebChromeClient(LoginCallback callback, GameProvider provider)
        {
            this.callback = callback;
            this.provider = provider;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result)
        {
            setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            if (provider.loginIsSuccess(Jsoup.parse(message)))
            {
                callback.onSuccess();
            }
            else
            {
                callback.onError("Неверный логин илм пароль");
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

В моем случае `WebView` нужен для скрытой авторизации (что-то вроде headless), так как недостаточно возможностей парсера. Если бы не было необходимости в JS, то `WebView` можно было бы выкинуть, но, к сожалению, Android не предоставляет ничего, даже подобного, взамен.

С одной стороны, да, `WebView` - это View (логично, правда?). Но View - отображение, тоесть то, что мы **видим**. В моем же случае он **скрыт** от пользователя и используется просто потому что иных инструментов нету. Поэтому я отношу его в слой **данных**. Это - платформоспецифичный репозиторий.

Но, к сожалению, создать `WebView` программно нельзя (а если и можно то контексту не место в слое данных). Значит, вариант с наследованием отпадает. Если же заменить наследование на композицию и передавать `WebView` через какой-то сеттер, то это значит, что View (она же в разметке!) должна пройти через все слои.

Оба варианта **ломают паттерн MVP**, но по сути своей логичны. Однако, как мне быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось как-то так:

```
class HeadLessLoginHelper(private val loginData: LoginData,
                          private val provider: GameProvider,
                          private val loginCallback: LoginCallback) : WebViewClient() {

    private var loginScriptInjected = false

    override fun onPageFinished(webView: WebView, url: String?) {
        super.onPageFinished(webView, url)
        if (!loginScriptInjected) {
            loginScriptInjected = true
            webView.runJavascript(readAsset(provider.loginScriptPath), loginData.login, loginData.password)
        } else {
            webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            webView.webChromeClient = JsAlertInterceptor()
            webView.runJavascript("function() { alert(document.documentElement.outerHTML); }")
        }
    }

    @Suppress("OverridingDeprecatedMember")
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
        webView.loadUrl(url)
        return true
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webView: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): Boolean {
        webView.loadUrl(request.url.toString())
        return true
    }

    override fun onReceivedError(webView: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest?,
                                 error: WebResourceError?) {
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        loginCallback.onError(ConnectException())
    }

    inner class JsAlertInterceptor : WebChromeClient() {

        override fun onJsAlert(webView: WebView, url: String,
                               message: String, result: JsResult?): Boolean {
            webView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
            val host = Uri.parse(url).host
            val afterHost = url.split(host)[1]
            try {
                provider.checkLoginResult(host, afterHost, Jsoup.parse(message))
                loginCallback.onSuccess()
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                loginCallback.onError(ex)
            }
            return false
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun login(webView: WebView, loginData: LoginData,
                  gameProvider: GameProvider, onSuccess: () -> Unit, onError: (Exception) -> Unit) {
            val loginCallback = LoginCallback(onSuccess, onError)
            webView.webViewClient = HeadLessLoginHelper(loginData, gameProvider, loginCallback)
            webView.loadUrl(gameProvider.loginUrl)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

WebView - это вьюха которая помещается на Активность и по идее , Активность эта и есть view в паттерне mvp

Comment: Но нет. Тут нельзя так быстро вердикт дать. Давайте спорить.

Comment: В моем случае WebView нужен для скрытой авторизации, так как недостаточно парсера. Если бы не было необходимости в JS то это можно бы было написать как модель

Comment: Следовательно, так как кроме WebView нет другого инструмента, позволяющего уверенно работать с JS на сайтах, я бы отнес этот случай использования WebView к слою данных

Comment: По сути получается некий платформоспецифичный репозиторий.. В конкретно моем случае

Comment: Это конечно все хорошо. Если бы WebView был независим от разметки. Но нет, он обязан в ней быть, я его обязан искать и с ним работать. Суть MVP сломана

Comment: А если заменить наследование на композицию, то WebView можно будет сделать в чистом виде но потом гнать его в слой данных..